# Real path of Android pictures from photo gallery

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-modules

I would like to do image processing on pictures from the photo gallery.

So, I'm working on module that works on android Bitmap by reading an image file.
From my Titanium application, I open the photo gallery and send the event.media.file.nativePath to my module.

But, it seems that it can't find it because when I create a

```
File file = new File(path)
```

I get a file.exists() == false. The path I get from the media looks like this on my phone :
file:///content://........../data/data.........jpg

Is there a way to create an Android Bitmap from media of Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery ?

Answer (score 0):

"file:///content://........../data/data.........jpg"
This file path seems to be like on BlackBerry. On you can get external storage like this:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Then you can add path to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Please! try below sample code.

```
Uri selectedImageUri = **put your content url**;
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
 cursor = getContentResolver().query(
, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
.moveToFirst();

 columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
 filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```